# Using JAX-WS RI of java 6 under heavy load

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-ws, java-6

I have recently started with web services. In my project, I have to create a client side using wsdl provided.
I have implemented the client part using JAX-WS RI which is available as part of Java 6. 
Now when I was going through some blogs, they mentioned that we should not use JAX-WS of java, as it is just an reference implementation and 
we have to go for libraries like Apache CXF or Axis2.

Could you please advice if we can use JAX-WS RI of java in production ?
At the moment with JAX-WS RI of Java, our client application testing is going on without any issues. Will it create any problem if we use it under high load ?

Thanks,

Vijay